# SaltStack File Server Access Control

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to have different security levels for different minions. I already have different pillars, so a secret ssh key for one minion can not be seen from another.

What I want to attain is: that an easy-to-attack minion, say an edge cloud server run by someone else, cannot download or even see the software packages in the file-roots that I am installing on high-security minions in my own data center.

It appears that the Salt file server, apart from overloaded filenames existing in multiple environments, will serve every file to every minion.

It does not seem that this is possible in any way, using environments, pillars, or clever file-root includes to make certain files inaccessible to a particular minion?

Answer (score 2):

By design the salt file server will serve every file to every minion.

There is something you could do to work around this.

Use a syndic. A minion can only see the file_roots of the master it is directly attached to, so you could have your `easy-to-attack` minions connect to a specific syndic, but you could still control them from the top level master that the rest of your minions connect directly to.

Comment: syndic is the answer

I will start with a dockerized syndic on the master and see how that turns out.
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/topology/syndic.html