# Troubles running multiple salt-master

Tags: salt-stack

Why is this not working?

I want to run multiple masters to serve different file sets.

I created this salt state launching a number of secondary salt-masters which appears to be working. Until they launch. Then zeroMQ exits with code None about 3 per second.

version: 2015.8.8+ds-1 Ubuntu 16.04

Lots of Log output of the following:

> 2016-08-25 23:23:02,461 [salt.transport.zeromq][INFO    ][12120] Worker binding to socket ipc:///var/run/salt3/master/workers.ipc
>
> 2016-08-25 23:23:02,475 [salt.utils.process][INFO    ][12116] Process <bound method ZeroMQReqServerChannel.zmq_device of <salt.transport.zeromq.ZeroMQReqServerChannel object at 0xb3ddae0c>>
> (12553) died with exit status None, restarting...

Configuration of a secondary master instance:

```
publish_port: 502
ret_port: 503
pidfile: "/var/run/salt-master2.pid"
pki_dir: "/etc/salt2/pki/master"
cachedir: "/var/cache/salt2/master"
sock_dir: "/var/run/salt2/master"
roster_file: "/etc/salt2/roster"
worker_threads: "3"
file_roots:
  base:
    - /home/data/salt/file2
fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git
gitfs_remotes:
    - file:///home/data/salt/saltgit/salt-formula
pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /home/data/salt/pillar
ext_pillar:
  - file_tree:
      root_dir: /home/data/salt/filepillar
      follow_dir_links: True
log_level: "info"
```

Comment: Can you describe why you want to run multiple masters in more detail? Perhaps using [multiple environments](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html#multiple-environments) with just one master would serve your purpose?

Comment: It is for security reasons. I want cpus not in my physical possession to have a subset of file_roots accessible. salt-syndic was suggested, but I am starting with just multiple master instances that have less things going wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777487/saltstack-file-server-access-control

Comment: In the above log output, I am trying to run one regular salt-master, and then a master2 and a master3 serving lower security zones